# Is there a hook in Retrofit to get the last request details?

Tags: android, retrofit, acra

I'm using ACRA to report exceptions and would like to include the last API call (and potentially the response body) as part of the custom data that can be supplied.  I've been looking over the available [RestAdapter.Builder interfaces](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RestAdapter.Builder.html) but don't see one that supplies what I'm looking for.  Effectively, I'd like access to what's put into Logcat when full logging is enabled.

Is there a way to get the last URL, headers, and response body within Retrofit so I can set custom ACRA fields?

Answer (score 2):

Retrofit allows specifying a [`Profiler`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/Profiler.html) which gets invoked immediately before and after requests are made.

```
public interface Profiler<T> {
  T beforeCall();
  void afterCall(RequestInformation info, long elapsedTime, int statusCode, T beforeData);
}
```

While you don't get access to the actual body, you get a good bit of information about it.